# TypeScript Union Types number or specific string

Tags: typescript, types, typescript2.0, union-types

I am experimenting with typeScript Union Types.
I have a class with a numeric property, but I want it to have three special cases: Infinity, None and Auto

Infinity and None can be represented with `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `NULL` respectively, but I don't know what to do about the auto-value.

This value originally comes in an XML-document represented as a string. For example `<element myValue="123"/>` `<element myValue="-4096"/>` `<element myValue="infinity"/>` `<element myValue="auto"/>` or `<element/>`

How can I create a union type that can be used as a number but still have the auto value available. I thought about a union type with number and Enum but I am not sure how to make the best out of it.

Any tips?

```
class MyClass {
    name: string;
    duration: number; // Want to support None/Null, Infinity and Auto
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using the string literal `'auto'` in your type annotation:

```
class MyClass {
    name: string;
    duration: number | undefined | 'auto';
}
```

(Here I use `undefined` instead of `null` to represent a missing value. If you're not yet using TypeScript 2.0, omit the `undefined`.)

This type annotation allows you to assign numbers (including `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`), `undefined`, and `'auto'` to `duration`, but not any other string.

Sample usage:

```
var c = new MyClass();
// ...

if (c.duration === undefined) {
    // ...
} else if (c.duration === 'auto') {
    // ...
} else {
    // In this branch, the type of c.duration will be number.
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This looks awesome! Just what I was looking for! I looked into string literals earlier but I got compiler errors. Perhaps I am using an old version of the typescript compiler. Will look into upgrading to TypeScript 2.0.

Comment: @user3336731: String literal types were introduced in TypeScript 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know what to do about the auto-value

Neither would we. You need to give an example of an auto value e.g. is `1` a valid `auto` value. I suspect it is and I suspect *all* numbers are valid. So I would use the type annotation `duration : number | null`

Comment: 1 is not an auto value. Auto is a value of its own which should trigger special logic down the line, so I need to use "auto" as a value as I can with "null". Michael Liu's answer looks like what I need.